# SQL Server stops every 24 hrs

Tags: sql-server

I have this weird issue with my SQL Server it always stop every night at 2 or 3 am Singapore time and I wonder why it's happening. Then in order for me to start it back again I have to restart the whole VPS for it to start back again. I have tried to find answer over the google but I don't have it.. the services I put automatic start. Is there possibility that SQL Server has its own timer to shutdown by itself?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked in the SQL Server logs to see any messages just before shut down or upon restart?

Comment: I've seen cases where virtualization-aware backup tools will pause/suspend the virtual machine while grabbing a snapshot-style backup. Perhaps you have something like that that is misbehaving and causing the SQL services to stop. Check your VM backup jobs and see if any of them correlate with the timing you are seeing.

Comment: Also, check the Windows event logs and see if there is an explanation for why the service stopped.